# Unable to login protect routes in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, node-modules

After login a user is only supposed to access some routes, but the code I wrote is able to protect only one route even when I login successfully and visit a specific route, it redirects me back to login. It is not supposed to do that because I am already logged in.

My code:

```
module.exports = function checkAuthentication(req,res,next){

   if(req.isAuthenticated()){
      return next()
   } else {
      res.redirect("/sign-in")
   }
}
```

The above code is used for authentication, after that I require it in `book.js` and `author.js` files, but it is not working correctly.

What am I missing?

Comment: Add code pieces from `book.js` and `author.js` where you import it and use it

Comment: in my books.js i required the function above as                                                            => const checkAuthentication = require("./auth")      then i used it in get function as                                                                                                                                                   
router.get("/allBooks",checkAuthentication,(req,res)=>{
getBook.find().sort( {createIndexes:-1} ).limit(2).then((result)=>{
  res.render("books/allBooks",{nData:result})
  } ).catch((err)=>{
      console.log("unable to find the user!")

  })

  } )

Comment: @Anatoly please guide me through this , thanks

Comment: Please add all code pieces to your post and not comments

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65455319/protecting-routes-in-nodejs-not-working-correctly?noredirect=1#comment115721929_65455319  @Anatoly